# Como aumentar o tamanho do traço e a calha entre eles em uma linha tracejada no css?

Tags: css

Estou precisando criar uma borda tracejada como no exemplo abaixo.

[image: Foto de referÊncia]

No figma defini que o traço teria 8px e o espaço entre eles também.

```
.newItemContainer
  border-radius: 8px
  border: dashed 1px colors.$stroke
```

O código acima foi o que usei para fazer a borda tracejada, porém não sei como especificar os valores para tamanho do traço e o gap.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O CSS não tem controle sobre o *espaço* entre os tracejados. Cada navegador pode renderizar isso de forma diferente. A *largura*, entretanto, é sim renderizada de forma comum, já que é uma informação da propriedade aceita em todos os navegadores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode usar um `rect` de `svg` com 100% de altura e largura do container. Nos atributos `stroke-dasharray: 8;` e `stroke-dashoffset: 22;` vc controla a linha tracejada que na verdade está no `svg` :D. No `rx="18" ry="18"` e no `border-radius` no css vc controla a curvatura das bordas do card.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da img acima:

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  line-height: 160px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 1.5s;
  position: relative;
}
svg {
  border-radius: 17px;
}
svg,
svg rect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  fill: transparent;
}
a svg rect {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 4;
  transition: all 500ms;
  stroke-dasharray: 8;
  stroke-dashoffset: 22;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <svg>
    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="18" ry="18"></rect>
  </svg>
  +
</a>
```

Comment: Hugo, muito obrigado, achei sua solução bem legal. 

Embora eu não tenha aplicado, antes que você respondesse eu acabei localizando uma ferramenta do css trick que ajudou a manipular a borda usando background-image. 

Mas desde já agradeço por ter dedicado um tempo para me ajudar e peço desculpas pela demora para retornar.

Comment: @GabrielFrança legal que resolveu! E valeu pela força, esses truques com SVG muitas vezes salvam o dia, mas.o background-image tb é um recurso muito interessante! Sucesso, abs!